# Providing synchronous and asynchronous methods as part of an API using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I have the following Java static instance, `MyRegistry`, which is used to invoke service layer methods.

Up until now it operated in a synchronous fashion, providing 2 methods.

```
public final class MyRegistry {

  private static MyRegistry instance;

  public static MyRegistry getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new MyRegistry();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public <T> T invoke(MyService myService, String methodName) {
    return myService.invoke(methodName);
  }

  public <T> T invoke(MyService myService, String methodName, Object[] params) {
    return myService.invoke(methodName, params);
  }
}
```

There is now a requirement to provide 2 new asynchronous methods, using `CompletableFuture` instances as the return objects.

I'm confused about how these 4 method signatures should be written.

The 4 signatures below were suggested, the idea is that all methods regardless of sync/async would return a `CompletableFuture`.

However wouldn't this mean it would be up to the consumer of the API, whether the operation is done synchronously or asynchronously based on the method they invoke on the returned object?

i.e by using either `.get()` to block or `.thenAcceptAsync` to run async, on the returned `CompletableFuture`?

Meaning, what would be the point of providing `invoke` vs `invokeAsync` alternatives?

```
public CompletableFuture invoke(MyService myService, String methodName, Object[] params) {

}

public CompletableFuture invoke(MyService myService, String methodName) {

}

public CompletableFuture invokeAsync(MyService myService, String methodName, Object[] params) {

}

public CompletableFuture invokeAsync(MyService myService, String methodName) {

}
```

Comment: `Future` and `CompletableFuture` always mean that the call will be asynchronous calls, the blocking methods should return the expected return type `T`

Comment: The caller does *not* decide whether the operation is asynchronous or not. When the caller chains an operation via `thenAcceptAsync`, the chained operation will be asynchronous, but that does not affect your operation. But does your old declaration really looks like `public <T> T invoke(MyService myService, String methodName)`? That basically promises to return whatever the caller wishes (the method doesn’t even know what `T` is).